# change the "remove" text after the image upload

Tags: drupal-7

Does anyone know how to change the value "remove" which show after image upload. eg from remove to delete or an image icon.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Three ugly ways to do this:

- You can do it with a Drupal JS behavior: change the value of the button or hide the remove button and create your own markup that fires the "remove" button with some event (click by default).
- You can do this with CSS with background simulating text and a very high negative text, display block and overflow hidden and stuff like that.
- I think you can do this with a hook_form_alter, if you can get the renderable array of the the form after the upload. You could try.

Hope that helps!